# jquery eval on <pre> tag to <script></script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with a jquery plugin here, which I am trying to use, but unfortunately, the example uses `eval` on `pre` tags to run the code. An example of this is [here](https://github.com/hpbuniat/jquery-popunder/blob/master/index.html).

In a nutshell, the author has some `<pre>` tags like so:

```
<pre>
//code
</pre>
```

and then runs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('form[action="#"]').attr('action', document.location.href);
    $('pre').each(function(i, e) {
        eval(e.innerHTML);
    });
});
</script>
```

My question now is how do I use the code within the `<pre></pre>` tags as script tags. So, when I do:

```
<script>
//// code from <pre></pre> tag
</script>
```

.. the code fails to work... Any directions to solve this mystery would be nice.

Comment: Is there any error output in the console? Would be helpful

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but can you not simply navigate the DOM of e to get the content of the pre tags, then eval that? What is the content of e.innerHTML?

Comment: @Dario: I see no errors on the console :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery functions and <script> tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160656/jquery-functions-and-script-tags). Please don't ask the same question twice...

Answer (score 0):

If you'd just change the "pre" to "script" you will probably cause the code withing the tags to run on the load of the page.
What do you desire to accomplish?

Comment: when I load the script with the "pre" tags, everything works as expected i.e the pop unders work as expected. but, when i change it to "script" it does not work anymore.

Comment: the "pre" tag is simple (preformatted)text element.
the "script" tag is a special tag to execute the text in it as java script.
if you just change it to "script" the code withing the tag will automatically execute on the load of the page.
I don't think that changing the tag name is your ultimate goal. what is your desire?